# Pass NavigationExtras to routerLink in template

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I want to disable changing the URL when routing in my Angular 2 app.

I know that `skipLocationChange: true` has to be passed as a `NavigationExtras` parameter to the router.

My question is:

#### Is it possible to pass NavigationExtras to a routerLink from inside the template?

What I have tried:

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['route1', { skipLocationChange: true }]">Route1</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['route2', { skipLocationChange: true }]">Route2</a></li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

but it does not work.

After clicking a link, the route changes to `http://localhost:4200/route2;skipLocationChange=true`

I don't want to use `this.router.navigate(['route1], {skipLocationChange: true)` in my controller, since then I lose `routerLinkAtive` highlighting.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

<strike>There is no way (for now and afaik) to both have `routerLinkActive` and `skipLocationChange` simultaneously and expect the result you want. You can, according to the [**api**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html), add options, but there is no `skipLocationChange` option.</strike>

You can however use the `NavigationExtras` from the router in combination with [**ActivatedRoute**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html) and base upon that whether or not the link should be active

**update**

Since `2.3.0-beta.0` you can add the `skipLocationChange` option to the `routerLink` directive:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['route1']" [skipLocationChange]="true">Route1</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll use the `router.navigate()` method and try to work out the active route highlighting some other way.

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski I've updated my answer. With the latest version of angular2 you can do what you want :)

Answer (score 9):

you can provide any of the NavigationExtras properties on the routerLink tag itself as individual attributes.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="{debug: true}" fragment="education">
  link to user component
</a>
```

the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) on RouterLink attributes
 is clear.

Comment: You can pass any of `queryParams`, `fragment`, `queryParamsHandling`, `preserveFragment`, `skipLocationChange`, `replaceUrl`, `state` (verified in source for router_link directive) https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts)

Answer (score 2):

`skipLocationChange` property is `false` by default. It will ensure to display the navigation url in the browser. If we want to hide the navigation url, `skipLocationChange` property should be made as `true`.

It can be achieved in two ways.

1. Passing object containing `skipLocationChange` property to the router object reference as below mentioned:

   ```
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/someUrlPath', { skipLocationChange: true });
   ```

This should be inside the component `.ts` file

2. Applying `skipLocationChange` directive to an HTML `<a>` anchor tag with the `routerLink` directive as below:

   ```
   <a [routerLink]="['someUrlPath']" [skipLocationChange]="true"> NameOfTheUrl</a>
   ```

This would be inside the template `.html` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working in angular v12 and this is what worked for me. I'm also using a named router-outlet, so I didn't want to see the ugly url it produces.

```
 <button type="button"
  [routerLink]="['/home', { outlets: {subpanel: ['sub-panel']}}]"
  (click)="onShowSubPanel()"
  [skipLocationChange]="true">
  Show Sub-Panel
</button>
```